# Create dynamically individual cards using Fetch method

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I'm working on a project which aim to make me use fetch to generate dynamically products card.

I've achieved to reach and use informations within the JSON file however my items got generated inside the same div instead of filling one by one product-card (div)

```js
main();

function main() {
  const getJsonData = fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cameras')
    .then(response => response.json());

  getJsonData
    .then(function(dispatchData) {
      const products = dispatchData;

      for (let item in products) {

        /*Implémentation de la carte - Card*/
        let getPrincipalContainer = document.getElementById("products");
        let createCard = document.createElement("div")
        createCard.className = 'product-card';
        getPrincipalContainer.append(createCard)

        /*Implémentation de l'img - IMG*/
        let generatingImg = document.querySelector(".product-card")
        let createImg = document.createElement("img")
        createImg.className = "card-img-top";
        createImg.src = dispatchData[item].imageUrl
        generatingImg.appendChild(createImg)

        /*Implémentation du Nom - Name */
        let generateName = document.querySelector(".product-card")
        let createName = document.createElement("h2")
        createName.className = "card-title"
        createName.innerText = dispatchData[item].name
        generateName.appendChild(createName)

        /*Implémentation du prix - Price*/
        let generatePrice = document.querySelector(".product-card")
        let createPrice = document.createElement("p")
        createPrice.className = "product-price"
        createPrice.innerText = dispatchData[item].price
        generatePrice.appendChild(createPrice)

        /*Lien  vers la fiche produit - Link to product-sheet*/
        let generateLink = document.querySelector(".product-card")
        let createLink = document.createElement("a")
        createLink.className = "product-sheet-link"
        createLink.innerText = "Voir la fiche produit"
        generateLink.appendChild(createLink)
      }

    })
}
```

[image: My HTML]

Answer (score 1):

You are querying by classname, so shouldn't that give you an array of all elements with that class instead of the latest one you made(like you're probably expecting)?

Try replacing the query with the actual reference of the `product-card` you defined at the beginning of each iteration. Something like this:

```
main();

function main() {
  const getJsonData = fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cameras')
    .then(response => response.json());

  getJsonData
    .then(function(dispatchData) {
      const products = dispatchData;

      for (let item in products) {

        /*Implémentation de la carte - Card*/
        let getPrincipalContainer = document.getElementById("products");
        let createCard = document.createElement("div")
        createCard.className = 'product-card';
        getPrincipalContainer.append(createCard)

        /*Implémentation de l'img - IMG*/
        let createImg = document.createElement("img")
        createImg.className = "card-img-top";
        createImg.src = dispatchData[item].imageUrl
        createCard.appendChild(createImg)

        /*Implémentation du Nom - Name */
        let createName = document.createElement("h2")
        createName.className = "card-title"
        createName.innerText = dispatchData[item].name
        createCard.appendChild(createName)

        /*Implémentation du prix - Price*/
        let createPrice = document.createElement("p")
        createPrice.className = "product-price"
        createPrice.innerText = dispatchData[item].price
        createCard.appendChild(createPrice)

        /*Lien  vers la fiche produit - Link to product-sheet*/
        let createLink = document.createElement("a")
        createLink.className = "product-sheet-link"
        createLink.innerText = "Voir la fiche produit"
        createCard.appendChild(createLink)
      }

    })
}
```